# SimpleDateFormat and parseException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I am developing a Web application into GWT and I am using the Object DatePicker. This object retrieves the date in a defined format which I am translating into a String such as:

```
Wed May 14 2014 00:00
```

For me it is useful to use this date as String for some operations. However, for one of them I need the Timestamp object. For that reason, I am making use of the SimpleDateFormat object in the following way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
Timestamp tDateIni = new Timestamp(sdf.parse(sDateIni).getTime());
```

Yet, when I run the remote debug I get a ParseException. Do you know what could the mistake be? I think I am using in a bad format the SimpleDateFormat object in the part "E MMM", but I am not sure. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: have you debugged `sDateIni`?

Comment: Yes, the example of date I have writen is a copy&paste of the debug value os sDateIni

Comment: It's working fine for me at serve side.

Comment: I tried to debug as well. Works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the Locale object in the SimpleDateFormat object and now it works. Thank you for all your help and your comments!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse the date at **client side** in GWT then try with [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
DateTimeFormat dateTimeFormat=DateTimeFormat.getFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
Date date=dateTimeFormat.parse("Wed May 14 2014 00:00");
```

---

If you want to parse the date at server side then pass the time in milliseconds as long value instead of date string from client side and form the date back at server side using `new Date(timeInMills)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this from

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
```

It should be `EEE` instead of `E` to represent Weekdays like `Wed`

Below code, perfectly works (**TESTED**)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Wed May 14 2014 00:00";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm");
        try {
            Timestamp tDateIni = new Timestamp(sdf.parse(s).getTime());
            System.out.println(tDateIni.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("Parse Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It was the solution I used at the beginning, but looking up on Google I saw an example using only "E". It neither worked!

Comment: Exactly, the same exception!

Comment: @JoseHdez It works for me. There is something else wrong in your end.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format uses the day of the week format that requires "EEE" instead of "E". This is causing the exception when the program is trying to read in your date string. It is expecting one letter for the day of the week.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html